# log plot with fixed number format on one axis

Tags: pgfplots

How can I x- and y-axis in logarithmic, but use the "normal" number format only on the x-axis?

I tried some stuff, as seen in the work example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
     % still in logarithmic:
    xtick={1, 25, 50, 100},
    % obtuse and produces rounding errors in real examples, e.g, 63.99:
    % xticklabel={\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\tick}\pgfmathfloatexp{\pgfmathresult}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}},
    % changes both axes:
    % x tick label style={log ticks with fixed point},
    ymode=log,
    domain=1:100
    ]
    \addplot+ {ln(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
     % still in logarithmic:
    xtick={1, 25, 50, 100},
    % obtuse and produces rounding errors in real examples, e.g, 63.99:
    % xticklabel={\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\tick}\pgfmathfloatexp{\pgfmathresult}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}},
    % changes both axes:
    % x tick label style={log ticks with fixed point},
    ymode=log,
    xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}},
    domain=1:100
    ]
    \addplot+ {ln(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost: I have rounded the result: `    xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{round(exp(\tick))}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}` because for some values, e.g., 64, it produces non-integer values.

Comment: @Horus Yes, that is one way. Alternatively you could e.g. use `xticklabel={\pgfkeys{ /pgf/number format/fixed,
          /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
          /pgf/number format/precision=0}
 \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}`.