# Logarithmic plot using tikz ung pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, xetex, pgfplotstable, tikz-pic

I want to draw a logarithmic plot of wavelength and frequency. The x and y axes show an exponential plot. I want the representation to be a simple number. How do I change the labels on the axes?

Since the wavelength `λ = c/f`

the graph should get along without a data set, because one end value and one start value of the equation should be enough. How do you realize something like this?

c = speed of light = 299792458 m/s

I have added an example in the appendix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}\[
    width=0.9\textwidth,
    title=Umrechnung Frequenz in Wellenlänge,
    xlabel={Frequenz $f$ \[\unit{\MHz}\]},
    ylabel={Wellenlänge $\lambda$ \[\unit{\m}\]},
    xmin=0, xmax=1000,
    ymin=0, ymax=300,
    domain=0:1000,
    restrict y to domain=0:300,
    grid=both
    \]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please convert you code snippet to a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in order to help others help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...

1. log axis **can't** start from 0.
2. `\[ ... \]` is a command for displayed math, not a square bracket. Use square brackets when needed
3. You must give a `\pgfplotsset{compat...}` to avoid surprises
4. package `mwe` is not for MWEs (yeah, I know...)
5. why limiting `y`?
6. Adjust the formula, I just put `300/x` to put something there.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        width=0.9\textwidth,
        title=Umrechnung Frequenz in Wellenlänge,
        xlabel={Frequenz $f$ [\unit{\MHz}]},
        ylabel={Wellenlänge $\lambda$ [\unit{\m}]},
        xmin=1, xmax=1000,
        ymin=1, ymax=300,
        domain=1:1000,
        log basis y  = 10,
        grid=both
        ]
        \addplot [thick, blue] {300/x};
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See also [pgfplots: How can I customize number formatting styles for log plots based on the numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402405/pgfplots-how-can-i-customize-number-formatting-styles-for-log-plots-based-on-th) , [pgfplots ticklabel format logarithmic scale](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37782/pgfplots-ticklabel-format-logarithmic-scale) , and [log plot with fixed number format on one axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484779/log-plot-with-fixed-number-format-on-one-axis)